# Indexing for tables used in temporal query

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, indexing

I have one tables with structures:

```
 CREATE TABLE [dbo].[rx](
            [pat_id] [int] NOT NULL,
            [fill_Date] [date] NOT NULL,
            [script_End_Date]  AS (dateadd(day,[dayssup],[filldate])),
            [drug_Name] [varchar](50) NULL,
            [days_Sup] [int] NOT NULL,
            [quantity] [float] NOT NULL,
            [drug_Class] [char](3) NOT  NULL,
            [ofInterest] bit
            CHECK(fill_Date <=script_End_Date
PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED 
(
            [clmid] ASC
)


CREATE TABLE [dbo].[Calendar](
             [cal_date] [date] PRIMARY KEY,
[Year] AS YEAR(cal_date) PERSISTED,
[Month] AS MONTH(cal_date) PERSISTED,
[Day] AS DAY(cal_date) PERSISTED,
             [julian_seq] AS 1+DATEDIFF(DD, CONVERT(DATE, CONVERT(varchar,YEAR(cal_date))+'0101'),cal_date),
     id int identity);
```

I used these tables with this query:

```
;WITH x 
     AS (SELECT rx.pat_id, 
                c.cal_date, 
                Count(DISTINCT rx.drug_name) AS distinctDrugs 
         FROM   rx, 
                calendar AS c 
         WHERE  c.cal_date BETWEEN rx.fill_date AND rx.script_end_date 
                AND rx.ofinterest = 1 
         GROUP  BY rx.pat_id, 
                   c.cal_date 
         --the query example I used having count(1) =2, but to illustrate the non-contiguous intervals, in practice I need the below having statement
         HAVING Count(*) > 1), 
     y 
     AS (SELECT x.pat_id, 
                x.cal_date 
                --c2.id is the row number in the calendar table. 
                , 
                c2.id - Row_number() 
                          OVER( 
                            partition BY x.pat_id 
                            ORDER BY x.cal_date) AS grp_nbr, 
                distinctdrugs 
         FROM   x, 
                calendar AS c2 
         WHERE  c2.cal_date = x.cal_date) 
SELECT *, 
       Rank() 
         OVER( 
           partition BY pat_id, grp_nbr 
           ORDER BY distinctdrugs) AS [ranking] 
FROM   y
```

The calendar table runs for three years and the rx table has about 800k rows in it.  After the preceding query ran for a few minutes I decided to add an index to it to speed things up.  The index that I added was

```
create index ix_rx
on rx (clmid)
include (pat_id,fill_date,script_end_date,ofinterest)
```

This index had zero affect on the run time on the query.  Can anyone help explain why the aforementioned index is not being used?  This is a retrospective database and no more data will be added to it.  I can add the execution plan if needed.

Comment: Please learn ANSI join syntax.  Your queries use rather sophisticated SQL.  I find it jarring to see no `on` in the `from` clause.

Comment: @GordonLinoff I agree this is sophisticated and rather strange looking, but this typical design pattern was suggested by Joe Celko and I thought... why not use it?

Comment: What is the query supposed to do?

Comment: @ypercube This query finds the range of dates that a person was prescribed the a given number of drugs.  So if this person was prescribed 1 drug for 1-1-2013 to 1-14-2013 and six drugs from 1-15-2013 to 1-17-2013 you'd be able to capture which days they were being prescribed the most drugs.  if i didn't use a calendar table i couldn't do this (not to my abilities, anyway) because i was looking for distinct drugs in the timeframe and person could easily have been prescribed the same drug twice.  it would've been much easier if i could've used `count(distinct` in the over clause.

Comment: looks like i didn't post the last part to this query.  the last part is something like `select pat_id,min(cal_date) as staroverlap,max(cal_date) end_overlap,min(distinctDrugs) from cte group by pat_id,grp_nbr`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `clmid` field is not used at all in the query.  As such, I would be surprised if the optimizer would consider it, just for the include columns.

If you want to speed the query with indexes, start with the query where the table is used.  The fields used are `pat_id`, `drug_name`, `rx_ofinterest`, `fill_date`, and `script_end_date`.  The last two are challenging because of the between.  You might try this index:  `rx(pat_id, drug_name, ofinterest, fill_date, script_end_date)`.

Having all the referenced fields in the index will make it possible to access the data without loading data pages.

Comment: Thanks.  I ran into some SQL Server complaints using `script_end_date` in an index because it's a computed column. I'll test all these and see how they work.

Comment: If you can include it in the index, then great.  If not, include the columns that are used for the calculation.  Once you get beyond `fill_date`, it doesn't matter if you put the columns *in* the index or use `include` (because `fill_date` is compared using `>` instead of `=`).

Answer (score 0):

Because it is not an appropriate index. Create two index one on [pat_id] and the other on drug_name. –